# Getting an EXC_BAD_ACCESS error when trying to sort a bag

Tags: c++, macos, algorithm, exc-bad-access, bag

So I am trying to get the count of words in a file and insert that into a bag.  To improve processing times, I created a replace command that takes a reference to that object and switch it with the one before it so more common words are quicker to be incremented in the bag.  I am continually getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS Code 2 errors but am unaware of how these are created.  Below are the code blocks in question.

```
template<typename T>
void replace(T& item, T& item2)
{
    T value = item;
    T value2 = item2;
    item = value2;
    item2 = value;
}
```

and

```
template<typename T, int N>
void Bag<T,N>::add(T item)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < m_size; i++)
    {
        if (m_items[i] == item)
        {
            m_counts[i]++;
            while (i != 0 && m_counts[i] > m_counts[i-1]) {
                replace(m_items[i], m_items[i-1]);
                replace(m_counts[i], m_counts[i-1]);
                i--;
            }
            return;
        }
    }
    m_items [m_size] = item;
    m_counts[m_size] = 1;

    m_size++;
}
```

I read that it might be an infinite loop causing this but the while loop created should not be creating an infinite loop.  Any help is appreciated.  If the entire code needs to be posted, it can be found at:

Github Gist of code
https://gist.github.com/nohe427/ff1ce9bbeec78983aec3

Comment: It's strange, since I copied your whole code (from the git link), but couldn't reproduce the error. It gave correct results, ie. Length Frquency, Letter Frequency and Uniqueness percentage.

Comment: I got it on the second run and then would consistently get the error.  I am getting it on two different MacBook Pros.

Comment: Can you try it on some online IDE like [this?](http://ideone.com/)

Comment: I am reading a local file so I don't know if that would work...  I recently introduced dynamic memory allocation to the original code and it seems to be working for now so I am not sure if we should keep troubleshooting or what.